# Bulk API doesn't print debug messages to the logs

Tags: api, logging, bulk

We are experiencing an issue which looks like a different system user (possibly) is used to run asynchronous triggers when loading data with the Bulk API. The reason I think this is because of the following scenarios....

1) We load some data with the standard API, triggers are fired and we can see System.debug messages that are configured to be logged for the user that we run the load with. Everything is good.

2) We load the same data with the Bulk API, triggers are fired but we can not see the System.debug messages that are configured to be logged for the user the we run the load with.

We use the same user for both cases.

We need to see these debug messages to debug another issue that is caused by the difference in how the data is loaded. However nothing we do will allow us to see debug messages when running with the Bulk API.

This is incredibly frustrating. Is this something simple that we are missing in configuration or is this just a Salesforce "feature"?